# SQL Server 2008 R2 Inserting data check

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I was hoping someone could check my code for instering data into a table in SQL Server 2008 R2. I've been looking around for a while trying to figure out what the issue is with my code. I'm not sure whether or not its the formatting or the syntax. I've worked with databases before but its always had manual entry into the tables.

```
INSERT INTO (Topic, Location)
     VALUES ('Maths', '103')
```

I have a table thats pre-made already with Topic and Location already created but the error message that comes up is *'Unable to parse'* followed by 
*SQL Execution error. 
Error source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider. 
Error Message: Incorrect syntax near '('.*

Any help would be appreciated, if this has already been answered, sorry!

Comment: What are the data types of your columns Topic and Location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a table name...  you will need something like

```
INSERT INTO your_table (Topic, Location)
     VALUES ('Maths', '103')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table name.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (Topic, Location)
VALUES ('Maths', '103')
```